# Asset database for Electron desktop app?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

I'm a refugee from the Flex/Actionscript world and I am "porting" (basically rewriting) a large legacy Flex app to Javascript using Electron as the runtime engine. I'm learning as I go, doing small tests to explore the functionality and appropriateness of various javascript libraries and frameworks.

This is a "presentation" type desktop app using local files(e.g. a Powerpoint, Keynote, iTunes type app) and I need to enable a user to import, tag and organize many images and video assets. I need to be able to move/copy assets, deal with duplicate filenames, create a db record for each file, create groupings of files, etc. and then of course be able to access all of these at runtime.

While it would be fun to write this from scratch, it would be a lot of work and it occurred to me that there might be an existing library or CMS framework I could adapt for this. Is that idea misguided? Is there an existing solution for this type of requirement?

Comment: Have you tried Nodejs File System? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html Or fs-extra?

Comment: @Philip – thanks, yeah, I've worked with it a bit and it certainly needs to be part of whatever I end up with. I guess I was looking for something which dealt with the UI frontend –a tree view, file preview, etc. but after looking around at a number of projects, most are so tied into PHP or otherwise entangled that it would be more trouble than it's worth to try to adapt something to work with local files. Will probably end up using fs, pouchdb and writing it from scratch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am working on a project with  the same requirements about files manipulation and database records so let me give you some tips :

- Use a small footprint database (leveldb , nedb , lovefield ) because you will need to pack it inside the app.
- Do not call the fs module directly from the renderer process , always use ipc (for decoupling reasons).
- structure your app by separating the main (electron-main , node modules etc) files and the renderer (the view , client side js , images...) files
- You need a third party module for files and directories to make sure everything is running smoothly , i use mkdirp to ensure that the directory exists , you can use fs-extra too which is fine for handling both (fs doesn't like non-existing locations).
- if the files  are big in size , use streams to move assets , `createReadStream` and `createWriteStream` should be the only methods used to read  & write files.
- If you need to watch some directories , use chokidar , it is far more efficient than the fs.watch method.
- Use a framework for the viewpart , depends on what you are familiar with , but angluar , react , vuejs  will be a good choice.

Finally check this link , it will help you get an overview of the things you could use 
https://github.com/sindresorhus/awesome-electron

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks – yes, it helps and it nudged me past my misguided and time wasting attempts to wrestle some codebase which wasn't intended for this (and is beyond my JS experience level). I just spent an hour fiddling with **[RichFilemanager](https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager)** and getting nowhere – though it looked promising with the nodejs **[connector](https://github.com/servocoder/RichFilemanager/blob/master/connectors/nodejs/filemanager.js).** Thanks for the tip about streams.

Comment: Hey Sam - just fyi if you haven't heard of this [fs-jetpack](https://github.com/szwacz/fs-jetpack). Just came across it and it looks really useful and less nut & bolts than fs.

Comment: just checked it , and it seems to be a good choice , it will hide from you all the error handling process so less code to write , ty for the tip !